# Parents did not receive 3rd stimulus wait or?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stimulus

My parents got the first and second stimulus. Most americans got the third one today. For some reason my parents did not get the third one today.

When I check the **[Get My Payment](https://sa.www4.irs.gov/irfof-wmsp/notice)** status site it says `Payment Status - Not Available`, as shown in the screen shot below:

[image]

They are both retired and filed one joint tax statement electronically. Their only income is Social Security so their income is pretty low, they did not draw from their retirement accounts at all.

Do I wait and is the IRS still processing more stimulus payments or do I contact the IRS?  If the latter how does one go about contacting the IRS?

Comment: Does the FAQ link from the screenshot you posted address scheduling or status of payments?

Comment: I guess it does say the IRS will continue sending payments throughout 2021, but that is so generic I thought someone else knew something different.  Just seems strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:  The IRS should be processing most SSI/SSDI/Federal Railroad Pension recipient payments for the third stimulus payout this weekend, with most people seeing the money in their accounts by April 7, according to the IRS.

It appears that the Social Security Administration, which is responsible for managing the lists of recipients, failed to send the file to the IRS for inclusion in the first wave of payments, as they did with the first two stimulus payouts.  This has since been corrected, and everything should be disbursed by the middle of next week.

Comment: Definetly not income level combined they may be making 25k. Also direct deposit was there last two stimulus checks. Will wait.

Comment: Odd, but not unexpected for the government! (grin)  I feel your concern - the IRS has somehow "lost" my electronically-filed 2020 taxes, even though I have a receipt saying they got it from TurboTax.  Nothing surprises me anymore! (lol)  People who receive Social Security should automatically receive their money, but things DO get lost in the shuffle sometimes.  Hope it works out for you!

Comment: Read my update: Several people I know who collect Soc Sec have not received theirs either.  Interesting...